# react router redirects but does not render with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am trying to make a login page which will redirect to the home page after successful authentication. Here is the code.

routes.js

```
const createRoutes = (store, history) => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <AppLayout/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterContainer}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default createRoutes;
```

actions.js

```
export const login = (data, successPath) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(beginLogin());

    return makeUserRequest("post", "/login", data)
      .then((resp) => {
        if (resp.data.success) {
          dispatch(loginSuccess(data));
          browserHistory.push(successPath);
        } else {
          dispatch(loginError(resp.data));
        }
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  };
};
```

Login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  login = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const email = event.target.querySelector("input[name='email']").value;
    const password = event.target.querySelector("input[name='password']").value;

    this.props.login({
      email,
      password
    }, this.props.nextPathName);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.login}>
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
          <h1>{this.props.user.email}</h1>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  nextPathName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Login;
```

LoginContainer.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  let nextPathName = "/";
  try {
    nextPathName = ownProps.location.state.nextPathName;
  } catch(err) {
    // ignore
  }
  return {
    user: state.user,
    nextPathName
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, userActions)(Login));
```

reducer.js

```
// reducer for user actions
const user = (state = { isWaiting: false, authenticated: false, email: "", message: "" }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
  case REGISTER_USER:
    return { ...state, isWaiting: true };
  case REGISTER_SUCCESS_USER:
    return { ...state, isWaiting: false, message: action.data.message };
  case REGISTER_ERROR_USER:
    return { ...state, isWaiting: false, message: action.data.message };
  case LOGIN_USER:
    return { ...state, isWaiting: true };
  case LOGIN_SUCCESS_USER:
    return { ...state, isWaiting: false, authenticated: true, email: action.data.email };
  case LOGIN_ERROR_USER:
    return { ...state, isWaiting: false };
  default:
    return state;
  }
};

export default user;

export default combineReducers({
  user,
  routing: routerReducer
});
```

The login functionality is working correctly and when I am clicking the login button, the email in the component is printing correctly. After that the browser is changing to the new location which is "/", but the page is not being rendered, i.e. the view is remaining same even after the browser location has changed. I have looked into similar question answers on stackoverflow, but have not found any solution to my problem. I have even used `withRouter` but to no solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where is your reducer?

Comment: @PratheeshM ok, I am adding the reducer code too.

Comment: the reducer code is actually divided into two parts index.js and user.js I added them together. Hope it is understandable. @PratheeshM

Comment: what is this  code `          browserHistory.push(successPath);`

Comment: browserHistory is coming from

`import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export default createBrowserHistory();`

Comment: is this pushing the router path?

Comment: It is being used to redirect to / after successfully logging in

Comment: i think it should be called after the action dispatched successfully. since it is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to use one of the higher level Router components like : `<BrowserRouter>` if your web/app is hosted on a dynamic server
or `<HashRouter>` if your webs/app is hosted on a static server

routes.js

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
const createRoutes = (store, history) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <AppLayout/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterContainer}/>
      </div>
    <BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default createRoutes;
```

`<BrowserRouter>` is just a wrapper with a pre-built history so you can do same with custom history instance . You can read more [Here](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf)

Comment: `const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);` but this history is coming from here. Won't using BrowserHistory cause problem as I am using this history to work with redux.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the imperative `push` method, you could use the nice declarative `<Redirect />` component that comes with React Router:

```
{user.authenticated && <Redirect to={nextPath} />}
```

You can place this wherever it makes sense for you. Inside your Login component or at the top level (just making sure not to redirect over and over)

Comment: My intention was to put it in the action because I was reusing the login action during register too. Can I use `<Redirect />` in the redux action code?

Comment: no redirect is a component. if you put it in your `routes.js` file you only need to write it once